# Update the Value on Textfield in javafx after an event

Tags: java, javafx

I want to update the value on the `JavaFx textfield` after an event. I have a `RootScreen` which opens a `popup` and in that `popup` i have a `listview` . When a user select the item on that `listview`, it should update the value on the `texfield` in `RootScreen` .
This is the code for the action on the `button` which is present on every list item. Every listItem also has a `TEXTFIELD` and `button` to select it. I want the value on the `TEXTFIELD` to be on the `texfield` in `RootScreen`.**Kindly see the uppercase and lowercase as i tried to make it as understandable as possible.**

```
    public void initialize() {
            button.setOnAction(event -> {
                source = select.getParent();
//walletname is the name i want on textfield.
                walletName = textField.getText();
                getWalletName(walletName);
                Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();




            });

        }
        private void getWalletName(String walletName){

            profilePopup.SetText(walletName,rootScreenController);

        }
```

The `SetText` method is in the `Popup View Class`. The code for `SetText` method.

```
public void SetText(String walletName, OnClick onClick){
        onClick.onMouseClicked(walletName);
   }
```

I have a `interface OnClick`, which has a `onMouseClicked` method . The interface i implemented in `RootScreen`

```
public interface OnClick {
      void onMouseClicked(String name);


}
```

This is how I am overriding the method in the interface.

```
@Override
    public void onMouseClicked(String walletName) {
textfield.setText(walletname);
    }
```

But its not updating the value on the textfield.
I am new in java, so I am not sure what to do here.

Comment: Check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/51050736#51050736). It may help you figure this out.

Comment: btw: the inline markup in your question is __TERRIBLE__  - highlighting by upper case letters plus adding a code tag (which is for ... code, not words, not even class/field names) makes is very hard to read

Answer (score 0):

If you have a popup screen that populates the information from the ListView, I think it is best that if the ListView entry is an Object or an Object in a collection. That is the only way you can separate each entry on the ListView - pulling the information from the object instead of deriving it from the ListView a a singular item.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a runnable example I think you are way over complicating this you can use the `.setOnMouseClicked` functionality to simplify this

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField("Not the same");

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().add("Item 1");
        listView.getItems().add("Item 2");
        listView.getItems().add("Item 3");
        listView.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {//You can change this if need be
            textField.setText(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(listView, textField);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

for more information on listView check out [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) you also may want to look at the object properties [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)